Why does Together speed up RowReduce?
Try the following code
$Version
(*"14.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"*)
mat = Table[
   Sum[RandomInteger[{-200, 200}]/
     If[# == 0, 1, #] &[RandomInteger[{-200, 200}]] x^i, {i, 0, 9}], 
   9, 9];
RowReduce[mat ]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{1.2897824`,Null}*)

RowReduce[mat // Together]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.0770588`,Null}*)

Can anyone explain it?

Why is it that Version 12 cannot be reproduced? I believe it is related to the faster polynomial operations introduced in Version 13.2. Nevertheless, for an unknown reason, polynomials with fractional coefficients are unable to make use of the faster polynomial operations.

Perhaps try to give another title to make it easier for people to find the post (later) as well as help you. Something like: " Why does Together speed up RowReduce?

I use v12.2.0 on Win7-x64. I see 1.25321, vs 1.25354, so everyone please indicate the version as well using $Version.

On V 14.1 I get similar result to the one by OP.  https://i.sstatic.net/rUuiPrzk.png  my guess is this: when doing Together, the polynomial entries get into form which makes later polynomial operations on them faster. see https://i.sstatic.net/XI1wTMoc.png  and there are lots of polynomial divisions going on to make the pivot of each row unity. each row on the matrix is divided by the pivot to make the pivot 1. It seems when the polynomials (matrix entries) are in the form generated by Together vs. the original form, these divisions happen much faster. This is just a guess ofcourse.

The difference (in Mac ARM V14.1) is that an internal solver works on mat // Together but not on mat. I could not spelunk deeper to discover why. Probably need to consult WRI support to obtain more information.
Algebra`URatMatDiagDecomp[x, mat // Together, 0]
(*
{{Algebra`PolynomialFunction[..]..},
  Algebra`UnivariateRationalMatrixFunction[..]}  
*)

Algebra`URatMatDiagDecomp[x, mat, 0]
(*  Algebra`URatMatDiagDecomp[x, <..mat..>, 0]  *)

The above leads causes the following:
Algebra`URatMatRowReduce[mat // Together, 0]
(* 9x9 identity matrix *)

Algebra`URatMatRowReduce[mat, 0]
(*  $Failed  *)

In the case of mat, this is followed by more work and takes more time.
